# Now date time minus a date time column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following table

```
Employee    Designation             Time_In
   A         Manager          07:50:28 19 March 2015
   B         Cashier          07:55:28 19 March 2015
   C         Runner           08:09:38 19 March 2015
   D         Cashier          07:30:32 19 March 2015
   E         Asst Manager     09:11:46 19 March 2015
```

How can I calculate how long each person has been in for.
in a table like, considering `Time Now` `Time_In - Now()`

```
Employee    Designation            Time_In             Duration      Day_In 
   A         Manager         07:50:28 19 March 2015    02:09:42   19 March 2015
   B         Cashier         07:55:28 19 March 2015    02:04:42   19 March 2015
   C         Runner          08:09:38 19 March 2015    01:50:32   19 March 2015
   D         Cashier         07:30:32 19 March 2015    02:29:38   19 March 2015
   E         Asst Manager    09:11:46 19 March 2015    00:48:14   19 March 2015
```

Comment: So you seem to have your code working... `Time_In - Now()`. How doesn't this work?

Comment: What ttype is Time_In?

Comment: Is Time_IN data type other than `datetime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189794.aspx) function with SQL Server, which calculates the difference between the two dates. It can return the difference in different terms like `seconds`, `minutes`, `hours` etc.

Here is an example to get the difference in hour between two dates.

```
DATEDIFF(hour, Time_In, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Employee, Designation, Time_In, 
DATEDIFF(hour, Time_In, GETDATE()) + ':' + 
DATEDIFF(minute, Time_In, GETDATE()) + ':' + 
DATEDIFF(second, Time_In, GETDATE()) AS Duration, Day_In
FROM table
```